# Prepend folder to PATH

Tags: command-line, paths, zsh, .profile

I want to append my anaconda folder to the beginning of `$PATH` so that I can use python and pip from Ananconda

Here is my `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories

export PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/opt/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/opt/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-3.2.10/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/heroku/bin
```

However, when I print out `echo $PATH`, the PATH always begins with `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` so that I have to use `/usr/local/bin/pip` instead of pip from my anaconda folder. How can I fix it?

Here is my PATH

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/USERNAME/opt/anaconda3/bin:...
```

By the way, I use `zsh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: or how about using soft links ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zsh doesn't use .profile it uses .zshrc or .zprofile

also you need to change your PATH exports to prepend not postfix

```
export PATH=:/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, `zsh` use `.zprofile` instead of `.profile`. I figure out in what happens in `.zprofile`:
`path=(
  /usr/local/{bin,sbin}
  $path
)`